# Submitting hidden data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I have short form in HTML. This is chat window and I would like to pass there not only user message but also some hidden data to file "post.php" which is in upper folder.

```
<form name="message" action="">
    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
    <input name="company" type="hidden" id="company" value="<?php echo $kawalki_adres[2]; ?>"/>
    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Here is AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //If user submits the form
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    var company = $("#company").val();
    $.post("../post.php", {text: clientmsg, company});              
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    $("#company").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});
```

I'm taking user's message correctly in "post.php" but not sure how to receive "company" variable.

Comment: You haven't set the company data in your `$.post()`, only the key. Change that line to this: `$.post("../post.php", {text: clientmsg, company: company}); `

Comment: You can simply use `var data = $('form').serialize()` and send that data to server inside $.post

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

> Make sure you are setting the value of company by PHP

```
$("#submitmsg").click(function(e){   
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents form submit, otherwise pages gets reloaded
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    var company = $("#company").val();
    $.post("../post.php", {text: clientmsg, company: company});              
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    $("#company").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});
```